# How to call Javascript code from android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to call JavaScript code given below and want to send some parameter to that code and based on that I want response from that script.

```
<script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/
    scripts/eCrypt.js"
    class="eway-paynow-button"
    data-publicapikey="XXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    data-amount="1000"
    data-currency="NZD" > 
</script>
```

Comment: What does that script do?

Comment: its a eway payment script for payment purpose.

Comment: You might be better off using the [eWAY Android SDK](https://www.eway.com.au/developers/sdk/android) rather than trying to run JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you would want to do that, but you can embed a WebView in your activity. From the looks of it above, the code creates a payment button. 
So: 
1. make your activity layout and put your webview wherever the button is supposed to be. 
2. create an HTML file where you put your code above. Put the HTML file in your assets folder 
3. In your activity, load the html file into your webview:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I just realized you want to pass parameters to this from the app. One way you could do this is instead of an HTML file, you can create an HTML string where you put your required information. So...

```
String html = "<javascript>blahblahblah</javascript>";
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android you just only call JavaScript from WebView like:

```
yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Hello World!')");
```

Comment: this is the code for  calling java script function , my  question is how to call that above script.

Answer (score 0):

Layout

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        android:id="@+id/webkit"        android:layout_width="fill_parent"        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Java Code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidJSWebView extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //WebView Object
    WebView browser;
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
    //Enable Javascript
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //Inject WebAppInterface methods into Web page by having Interface name 'Android' 
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    //Load URL inside WebView
    browser.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
}
//Class to be injected in Web page
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /**
     * Show Toast Message
     * @param toast
     */
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Show Dialog 
     * @param dialogMsg
     */
    public void showDialog(String dialogMsg){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("JS triggered Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(dialogMsg);

        // Setting alert dialog icon
        //alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Dialog dismissed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Intent - Move to next screen
     */
    public void moveToNextScreen(){
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
         // Setting Dialog Title
         alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
         // Setting Dialog Message
         alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave to next screen?");
         // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
         alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         //Move to Next screen
                         Intent chnIntent = new Intent(AndroidJSWebView.this, ChennaiIntent.class);  
                         startActivity(chnIntent);  
                     }
                 });
         // Setting Negative "NO" Button
         alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         // Cancel Dialog
                         dialog.cancel();
                     }
                 });
         // Showing Alert Message
         alertDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```